# Windows 2012 Webdeploy 3.0 does not allow to deploy to d: drive

Tags: windows-server-2012, deployment

I started brand new Windows 2012 with IIS 8 and Webdeploy 3.0 installed.
I could connect to it using VS 2012 to publish my application using Webdeploy method (test connection at VS).
But, here comes a magic: whenever I try to publish my application to custom folder, located on D: drive - VS generates an error:
ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_TO_SITE_FOLDER.
In Event log, following event is logged:

```
Content-Type: application/msdeploy
Version: 9.0.0.0
MSDeploy.VersionMin: 7.1.600.0
MSDeploy.VersionMax: 9.0.1631.0
MSDeploy.Method: Sync
MSDeploy.RequestId: f84d3e36-4785-4ebe-8a59-1fce9bd41ec3
MSDeploy.RequestCulture: en-US
MSDeploy.RequestUICulture: en-US
ServerVersion: 9.0.1762.0
Skip: objectName="^configProtectedData$"
Provider: auto, Path: 
A tracing deployment agent exception occurred that was propagated to the client. Request ID 'f84d3e36-4785-4ebe-8a59-1fce9bd41ec3'. Request Timestamp: '7/2/2013 5:52:53 AM'. Error Details:
ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_TO_SITE_FOLDER
Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentDetailedUnauthorizedAccessException: Unable to perform the operation ("Create Directory")  for the specified directory ("D:\inetpub\wwwroot\ixxi.acceptatie.colours.nl\website"). This can occur if the server administrator has not authorized this operation for the user credentials you are using.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_TO_SITE_FOLDER. ---> Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentException: The error code was 0x80070005. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\inetpub' is denied.
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.NativeMethods.RaiseIOExceptionFromErrorCode(Win32ErrorCode errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DirectoryEx.CreateDirectory(String path)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DirPathProviderBase.CreateDirectory(String fullPath, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DirPathProviderBase.Add(DeploymentObject source, Boolean whatIf)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.FilePathProviderBase.HandleKnownRetryableExceptions(DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, Int32[] errorsToIgnore, Exception e, String path, String operation)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DirPathProviderBase.Add(DeploymentObject source, Boolean whatIf)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.Add(DeploymentObject source, DeploymentSyncContext syncContext)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.HandleAdd(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.HandleUpdate(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenNoOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenNoOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.ProcessSync(DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable, Nullable`1 syncPassId, String syncSessionId)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleSync(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData, Nullable`1 passId)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleRequestWorker(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleRequest(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData)
```

However, as soon as I target my web application to be hosted anywhere on c:\ drive (c:\test) for example = publish runs without any issues

Comment: Forgot to mention, that for testing purposes I am using account, which belongs to Administrators group only

Comment: Resolved by installing Windows 2008 R2 web server. Works like a charm out there